# How can I serve mostly static pages from a scala Play! application like an "About" page in different languages?

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I am building an application using the Play! framework version 2.0.4. Some pages that are legally required such as an imprint mostly contain lots (some 10k each) of static text which I would like to provide in different languages.

In versions 1.x there was an `#include` directive that allowed to construct the actual resource path using the current `Lang`.

What is the recommended way of implementing sth similar with Play 2.x?

Thank you & best regards,
Erich

Comment: Why dont you keep your text in some file (or list or whatever) and given the language given to the view you get the correct text from said file. Im assuming you dont want to pass the text to the view from the controller.

Comment: Can you explain how you used `#include` to access your localized content? Maybe it's possible to build a similar helper.

Comment: I never used Play 1.x myself, but found out about #include when googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain how you implement it as of now, but here's what I've come up with.

You could just write your own include helper. Save the following in a file `Helpers.scala` in your views folder. Explanations are in the code's comments.

```
package views.html.helper

object include {
  import play.api.templates.Html
  import play.api.Play
  import play.api.Play.current
  import play.api.i18n._

  // The default is to look in the public dir, but you can change it if necessary
  def apply(filePath: String, rootDir: String = "public")(implicit lang: Lang): Html = {
    // Split filePath at name and suffix to insert the language in between them
    val (fileName, suffix) = filePath.splitAt(filePath.lastIndexOf("."))

    // Retrieve the file with the current language, or as a fallback, without any suffix
    val maybeFile =
      Play.getExistingFile(rootDir + "/" + fileName + "_" + lang.language + suffix).
      orElse(Play.getExistingFile(rootDir + "/" + filePath))

    // Read the file's content and wrap it in HTML or return an error message
    maybeFile map { file =>
      val content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).mkString
      Html(content)
    } getOrElse Html("File Not Found")
  }
}
```

Now in your `imprint.scala.html` you could call it like this:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
@import helper._
@include("static/imprint.html")
```

Comment: I have just implemented your suggestion - works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Way showed by **Schleichardt** was used in [`play-authenticate`](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) to select mail templates in different languages and now it's changed to work with reflections on the controller, so maybe it can be interesting for you. Anyway it was intendent to keep standard templating possibilities (cause each mail need to be personalized before send)

For static info pages, you can just save the code for each language with suffix ie. `impressum_en.html`, `impressum_de.html` in the file system and use simple controller which will find file with proper suffix and return its content exactly as it is... all you need probably to return Ok(fileContent) and set the Content-Type manually to `text/html`.

Other option is doing the similar thing but storing it in the DB, so you can create simple back-end and edit it with browser.

If you still need to replace some elements, you can do it with some `###MARKER###` in the code + simple String operations, or with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Thank you, I was already planning to do sth along these lines. Good to have a reference point for starting. Actually, Marius' answer is even closer to my vision.

Answer (score 0):

Templates in 2.0 work a bit differently. The Scala based templates are compiled. From one template instead of 'including' another, you can make a call to it. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the language thing. In 2.0 though, a parameter to the template could be the language.

Example template named 'included' in package whateverpackage.

```
@(lang: Lang)

...
```

Example calling a template named 'included':

```
@import whateverpackage._

@included(Lang("en"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I want to show completely different pages, say "About", e.g. for users with english and for others with german locale/lang. English should render sth like "About this site bla bla", whereas a German should see sth like "Über diese Seite bla bla". I do not want to use the standard I18N mechanism as the pages in question contain some 10k of text each.

Answer (score 0):

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)

@main(Messages("imprint")) {
    @lang match {
        case Lang("de", _) => { @germanImprint() @* uses app/views/germanImprint.scala.html file *@}
        case _ => { @englishImprint() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This could work but would force me to 1) have a separate controller for each such page and 2) to update the controller for each page once I add that page in another language. I am looking for a more general solution that e.g. employs patterns similarly to the standard I18N messages including falling back to english as default.

Comment: I see. I think you need to find or program some kind of content management system plugin.